# How to track user changes in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have a website built with Vue.js and I need to do an *audit* and, optionally, implement *cancel* functionality for this website so I'm looking for my options/best practices.

Let's say I have an *Items* array defined in `data()` so on `created ()` I'm doing an Ajax request and pushing data into this array of items.

Now user loads this page and does his job which for me means he changed a few  objects. Let's say each Item is  a `Customer` object and it has `First name`, `Last name`, `DOB` and a `IsActive` boolean field.

I would like to give this user an option to revert specific item to the original state without reloading anything and when he hits `Save` I would like to know what was changed (so I can log this information)

Here are my ideas so far:

1. keep a copy of the original list of Items and do a diff later to see what was changed or use it to restore objects as needed
2. try to utilize `watch()` and keep track of changes. Perhaps, I can even store this information in the object itself.
3. leave a UI *as is* and on the backend (while saving or updating) re-read object from the DB and do the job there since it is the only truly secure way of doing an audit anyway.

What's the best way to track changes and/or implement both *cancel* and *audit*?

Maybe there is a Vue-way of doing this which I'm missing, because I just switched to Vue from a different framework.

Thank you! Any help appreciated!

Comment: i hope that i understood you good, i suggest to create an array that tracks changes and each element inside this array has the following structure : changeItem:{ index, oldItem, newItem }, index represents the item position in the original items array

Comment: How about save is submitting a post request, and cancel is requesting data from server to overwrite current state?

Comment: In my opinion, for the `audit` part option (3) is optimal (you can even utilize the `temporal_tables` extension for PostgreSQL - http://clarkdave.net/2015/02/historical-records-with-postgresql-and-temporal-tables-and-sql-2011/), while for the `undo` part you can utilize the `Vuex undo/redo plugin` from https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/13/vue-js-vuex-undo-redo/

Comment: @Christ I definitely can do that, **but** let's say I loaded 100 items and user changed 3 of them and now user wants to undo 1 item, but keep other 2 in a `changed` state and keep working. This scenario is tricky: I can pull 100 items again (but I would prefer to avoid it), **but** I need to preserve 2 other items in a `changed` state. That's why my question is: "Is there any easy way to track changes?" 

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank sir, I'll take a look